# Can't redirect to another view/url

Tags: python, django, url, redirect

I have django app (1.8) and I want to have redirection from `BookingRedirect` to `ArchiveListView` after click link below:

```
<a href="{% url 'archive:list' %}" title="{% trans 'Archive' %}">
    {% trans 'Archive' %}
</a>
```

I recived this error:

```
Reverse for 'archives' with arguments '()' and keyword arguments '{'kwargs': {'year': '2014', 'month': '1'}}' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['en/archive/(?P<year>[0-9]{4})/(?P<month>[0-9]+)$']
```

My view where I want to have redirect to another url with another view:

```
from django.shortcuts import redirect


class BookingRedirect(RedirectView):
    permanent = False

    def get_redirect_url(self, *args, **kwargs):
        return redirect('archive:archives', kwargs={'year': '2014', 'month': '1'})
```

urls:

```
urlpatterns = [
    url('^$', views.BookingRedirect.as_view(), name="list"),
    url(r'^/(?P<year>[0-9]{4})/(?P<month>[0-9]+)$', views.ArchiveListView.as_view(), name="archives"),
]
```

Comment: You have an unnecessary leading slash in your pattern.

Comment: @DanielRoseman I removed this and nothing happend

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's not how you pass kwargs to the `redirect` function. You pass them directly as kwargs:

```
return redirect('archive:archives', year='2014', month='1')
```

See [the docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/http/shortcuts/#redirect).

Note, however, that your `get_redirect_url` should *not* be using that function at all. It needs to return a URL that the view itself then redirects to. So you need to use `reverse`, which *does* take kwargs in the format you used:

```
return reverse('archive:archives', kwargs={'year': '2014', 'month': '1'})
```